# fixed point datatype with PHP 5

Tags: php, floating-point, type-conversion, fixed-point

Am I wrong (I hope), but I don't find on PHP a fixed-point datatype !?

Datatype like DECIMAL/NUMERIC from MySQL will be nice for doing operations on money without precision loss.

Any ideas ?

Comment: You are not wrong ... php only has float.

Comment: If you're worried about precision loss, I'd recommend just using an integer value - keep track of the values in cents or tenths of a cent, instead of dollars.